# Problema ao executar arquivo .jar criado pelo Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estou tentando criar um executável utilizando o Intellij. Segui todos os passos no site oficial, alem de vários tutoriais no youtube. Consegui criar o  executável e rodar ele dentro da IDEA

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando tento rodá-lo pelo CMD aparecem as seguintes mensagens:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: teste/TesteCadastro has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Ainda não sei como resolver esse problema. Alguém com um bom coração poderia me ajudar?

Comment: a versão do java sua que está no seu classpath é mais antiga do que a versão que você está usando para compilar o jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão que você está usando para compilar as classes(dentro do Intellij) é a Java 13, mas, a versão da sua JRE(quem executa suas classes compiladas) é a versão Java 8.

Comment: Então basta atualizar a JRE?

Comment: Sim, ou, se não for utilizar as novas features do Java 13, troque dentro do Intellij para usar o Java 8.

Comment: @NahtanN, funcionou?

Comment: Ss, consegui resolver. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @NahtanN, seu feedback é muito importante pois serve de referência para outros usuários que estejam com o mesmo problema que você. Depois, não esquece de marcar como resposta para fechar este tópico. Bons estudos. (: